# Tokenizing and Indexing many files

Tags: java

I have to read several files and and index each word in the files.
while indexing i have to follow a format:

Requirement ==>   word , {d1,tf1,d2,tf2,d4,tf4} , someOtherValue

Explanation :

```
         1)word = any word in the files

         2)d1,d2,d4... are fileId

         3) tf1,tf2,tf4....are the number of times the word appears
            in d1,d2,d4 respectievly
```

I created a class "Token"  which contains words from different files as 'String token' ,  name of the file to which it belongs to as 'String fileId' and its frequency in the file as 'Int count'.

I can easily check for various words in 1 file and update its count.
I used arrayList to do so.
But when same word appears in another file how can i append the fileId and its count while indexing.

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of text search application. If yes then you can have a look at Lucene which does the indexing and searching part quite easy.

Comment: @Shailendra I have to do it inn java.thats the problem.Any suggestions??

Comment: If you mean Java language then Lucene is written in Java. If you have to develop a complete text search application on top of what you are trying to achieve then you can try Lucene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a

```
class RefCount {
    String fileId;
    int count;
    RefCount( fileId ){
        this.fileId = fileId;
        count = 1;
    }
    void increment(){
        count++;
    }
    // more...
}
```

And class Token should be

```
class Token {
    String word;
    List<RefCount> references;
    ...

    public void countWord( String fileId ){
        int last = references.size() - 1;
        if( last >= 0 ){
            RefCount rc =  references.get(last);
            if( equals(fileId) ){
                rc.increment();
                return;
            }
        }
        references.add( fileId );
    }
    // more...
}
```

This assumes that you are adding references file by file so only the last file id needs to be checked to determine whether we are still in the same file.

You should use a `Map<String,Token>` rather than a List.

**Edit** To display the results you can iterate the Map or List of all tokens, then the List of RefCount objects:

```
for( Token token: tokenList ){
    System.out.print( token.getWord() + ":" );
    for( RefCount refCount: token.getReferences() ){
        System.out.print( " " + refCount.getFileId() +
                          "*" + refCount.getCount() );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You may want to terminate a line after every n-th id/count pair.

Comment: I think it works.One last help.
How can I display all the words with respective fileID and counts??
Note : I am tokenizing the files in a class named Test and Test has the array List of Token type and Token has array List of RefCount .

Comment: @radhapiyari That's really easy: a nested loop is all you need.

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked.I made some modification in the codes above and it behaves the way i wanted.You are genius mate.
Cheers!!